# Spring web services, JMS transport and replay-to

Tags: spring, jms, spring-ws, spring-jms

I need to send a soap message to a queue and wait for the response into another.

The correlationId in the second one (the response queue) is the message Id in the first the message send to the request queue.

I'd like to use spring-ws but I am out of ideas. Could you please give me some advice or small example?

Comment: Why sending soap messages ? Can you explain. What did you mean by waiting response into another ? A jms client will be used for that to receive responses ?

Comment: @HassenBennour is a normal web service with jms transport instead of http. The difficult part comes, at least for me,  when the request and the response are in two different queues.

Comment: What is your message broker ? Did you mean that your broker exposes a webservice endpoint or you will send soap content in a jms message ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring integration like this example https://github.com/snicoll/scratches/blob/master/jms-request-reply/src/main/java/net/nicoll/scratch/spring/boot/jms/sync/JmsRequestReply.java

Or spring jms to do request-reply http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html